# Is there an easier way to hover transform: scale(); on svg rect?

Tags: java, css, svg, hover

I am currently playing around in a rather complicated SVG file. Im looking to make a fully interactive thermometer. Im trying to do a hover effect on multiple recs inside my svg file.
For every different rect there is a different center point, my question is if there is a way to do this in Javascript and make it calculate it for me.

Or is the only fix to have to manually calculate every center point and make a different hover in css for each one using transform origin?

this is how you calculate center point.
x = x + Width/2
y = y + height/2

### This is the svg's im looking to make a hover on with transform:scale ()

```
<rect x="127.1" width="155.17" height="602.02" rx="77.59" fill="#e0e1e2" id="termometer"/>
      <g id="stregerne"><rect class="cls-2" x="148.46" y="220.4" width="112.46" height="3.08" rx="1.54"/>
      <rect class="cls-2" x="148.46" y="257.5" width="112.46" height="3.08" rx="1.54"/>
      <rect class="cls-2" x="148.46" y="294.6" width="112.46" height="3.08" rx="1.54"/>
      <rect class="cls-2" x="148.46" y="332.21" width="112.46" height="3.08" rx="1.54"/>
      <rect class="cls-2" x="148.46" y="369.67" width="112.46" height="3.08" rx="1.54"/>
      <rect class="cls-2" x="148.46" y="407.13" width="112.46" height="3.08" rx="1.54"/>
      <rect class="cls-2" x="148.46" y="443.92" width="112.46" height="3.08" rx="1.54"/>
      <rect class="cls-2" x="158.79" y="238.95" width="91.81" height="3.08" rx="1.54"/>
      <rect class="cls-2" x="158.79" y="276.05" width="91.81" height="3.08" rx="1.54"/>
      <rect class="cls-2" x="158.79" y="313.4" width="91.81" height="3.08" rx="1.54"/>
      <rect class="cls-2" x="158.79" y="350.94" width="91.81" height="3.08" rx="1.54"/>
      <rect class="cls-2" x="158.79" y="388.4" width="91.81" height="3.08" rx="1.54"/>
      <rect class="cls-2" x="158.79" y="425.4" width="91.81" height="3.08" rx="1.54"/>
      <rect class="cls-2" x="148.46" y="103.26" width="112.46" height="3.08" rx="1.54"/>
      <rect class="cls-2" x="148.46" y="140.36" width="112.46" height="3.08" rx="1.54"/>
      <rect class="cls-2" x="148.46" y="177.46" width="112.46" height="3.08" rx="1.54"/>
      <rect class="cls-2" x="158.79" y="121.81" width="91.81" height="3.08" rx="1.54"/>
      <rect class="cls-2" x="158.79" y="158.91" width="91.81" height="3.08" rx="1.54"/>
      <rect class="cls-2" x="158.79" y="196.26" width="91.81" height="3.08" rx="1.54"/>
      </g>
```

```
    svg {
  transform: fill-box;
  transform-origin: center;
}
.cls-2{
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
     transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  transform-origin: 204.69px 259.04px;

}
.cls-2:hover{
  transform:scale(1.2);

}
```

This is the only solution i've found and it only works for a single one of the recs, the one where i calculated the center point.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that its the center point of the svg, not the different rects.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answers Robert, this looks exactly like what im looking for :)